# How should I handle redux store from being populated multiple times?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a component that fetches initial data:

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getNewsInitial(page));
  }, [page, dispatch]);
```

This data gets populated within redux, however, the issue is that when the component unmounts (by going to another react page, which does not include a full page refresh, only via react-router), and I come back to the component, the API request is made again, even though the data already exists within the store.

How do people usually handle this scenario? I know one way is to create a new store variable called `isLoaded`, but then I have to start managing that variable as well within reducers. If that's the main way to do it, then that's fine, but just wanted to make sure. I'm using axios and redux toolkit with slices by the way.

Thanks!

Comment: What about just checking if the state already exists before calling the fetch?

Comment: @Steve I was thinking about doing that too, however, the way that my setup is done is that once more data loading is needed, I have a separate redux action that will update the state's `page` variable, which should call the `getNewsInitial` API again with the updated page. But I did see that as a potential solution as well.